# pass element ID as a parameter to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box on a web form that, depending on what is selected, will show a hidden div.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Select1").change(function () {
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("Value")=="2"){

                $("#hiddentable11").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("Value")=="3"){

                $("#hiddentable11").show();
            }

            else{
                $("#hiddentable11").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

The form will have 35 to 40 of these Select box/hidden div combinations.  The option values in the select boxes will all be the same every time (0,1,2,3,4).  If the user chooses option 2 or 3 for Select1, hiddentable11 appears.  If they choose option 2 or 3 for Select2, hiddentable 12 appears  I don't want to copy/paste this code 40 times and in the code change Select1/hiddentable11 to Select2/hiddentable12, Select3/hiddentable13 etc.  How do I change this code so that I can reuse it for all of the select/div combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the select boxes a class, e.g. `class="select". Then you can use`this.id` to get the ID of the target element, and concatenate it to the DIV id.

```
$(".select").change(function() {
    var num = this.id.slice(6); // get N from id="SelectN"
    $("#hiddentable1" + num).toggle($(this).val() == "2" || $(this).val() == "3"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just make a `.Select` class, and use `this`, pass in the corresponding hidden table as a user defined unique data attribute (I'll use `data-hidden` as an example). Then you can create the proper selector for each item by doing `"#"+$(this).attr("data-hidden")`:

```
$(".Select").change(function () {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("Value")=="2") {
            $("#"+$(this).attr("data-hidden")).show();
        }
        else if($(this).attr("Value")=="3") {
            $("#"+$(this).attr("data-hidden")).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#"+$(this).attr("data-hidden")).hide();
        }
    });
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. With this you don't need to depend on ID's. You may multiple select boxes to your code and table combo and never have to change your js code.

```
<select id="select1">
    <option val="0">0</option>
      <option val="1">1</option>
      <option val="2">2</option>
      <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="hiddentable11">
    Hidden Contents of Select1
    </div>
<select id="select2">
    <option val="0">0</option>
      <option val="1">1</option>
      <option val="2">2</option>
      <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="hiddentable12">
    Hidden Contents of Select2
    </div>
<select id="select3">
    <option val="0">0</option>
      <option val="1">1</option>
      <option val="2">2</option>
      <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="hiddentable13">
    Hidden Contents of Select3
    </div>

$("select").change(function () {
        var index = $('select').index($(this));
        index++;
        var $this = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            $("#hiddentable1" + index).css("display", $this === "2" || $this === "3" ? "inline-block" : "none");            
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/njzatgku/1/